# Rails redirect instead of render with object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a tutorial I'm following. There is a signup portion of code that, when the validations don't pass, Rails renders the action again. That all works well but obviously the URL doesn't look the same:

http://localhost:3000/signup - Before hitting the button

http://localhost:3000/Users  - After hitting the button with invalid details

This is the code:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample Application!"
redirect_to @user
else
    render 'new'
end
```

Is there anyway to pass the @user object with redirect_to so that it displays the correct URL *and* populates the form (using form_for) with the details entered by @user?

Answer (score 0):

Well calling render just tells it to basically now use that partial. So the URL still matches the action specified (so in this case, /Users) even though the rendered view is different.

Here's how you can use redirect_to though:

```
redirect_to new_user_path(@user)
```

You can also be explicit with parameters like:

```
redirect_to some_path({:data => 1, :var => 2})
```

Comment: The only problem with that is I'm not able to pass the user object over to that new location. I need to use that user object to both populate the form and read the errors

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not really, since redirect_to lets the server respond with HTTP redirect response, that makes the client fetch the specified url. This means that the corresponding Rails action is called in a new context, wich makes it impossible to access the local variables like the user object.
The only thing you can do would be saving the user in the database anyway (maybe in some special temporary table) and then pass the id as get parameter or saving the data in a cookie and retrieving it in the called action to set the values on a new user object. 
However to me both options don't seem worth the effort for just having a correct url.